# Android Studio R Cannot be Resolved - Error on Clean and Gradle Build

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am currently working on an app for my own personal use but have 1000001 problems with Android Studio - now R cannot be resolved - and cleaning gives the result below:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
Error: Failed to run command:
C:\Users\William\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\aapt.exe s -i C:\Users\William\Dropbox\111 WORKSPACES 111\Android Studio\Legacy\Notifications Alarm\2015-03-24 AndroidStudioProject\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\21.0.3\res\drawable-xhdpi\abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png -o C:\Users\William\Dropbox\111 WORKSPACES 111\Android Studio\Legacy\Notifications Alarm\2015-03-24 AndroidStudioProject\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png
Error Code:
    42
Output:
C:\Users\William\Dropbox\111 WORKSPACES 111\Android Studio\Legacy\Notifications Alarm\2015-03-24 AndroidStudioProject\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\21.0.3\res\drawable-xhdpi\abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 17.777 secs
```

Above is the error message I keep on receiving when I clean my project. I can't find any XML errors, I have no foreign bodies in my resources except the launcher picture, and I can't find my R file anywhere - let alone reference it without error. The above error points to a

```
abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png
```

That I have found and deleted - I don't think this is the right solution as the error persists. I have update Android Studio synched the Gradle and everything I have seen from my research. I really don't know how to handle this.

Thank you.

Comment: What happens if you delete your `app\build` directory?

Comment: change name to `abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha_9.png`

Comment: that wouldn't do it, .9.png is a special format that should've been recognized

Comment: Ah yes to echo the last comment it seems tons of files are name .9.png and when I changed the name it was automatically changed back. I'm about to delete app\build as suggested and rebuild again

Comment: Rebuilt! Build app\build was remade - but got the same error. The presence of the error has me ruling out XML error (especially since I didn't see any) - could XML still be the issue? I don't understand how it could get an error reading its own generated files